# Difference between two arrays of Mongo Document _ids

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, lodash

Essentially, I have two arrays of _ids from Mongodb that I'm trying to compare/get the differences of.

Array 1 comes directly from a document.find() call.  Array 2 comes from an document.Aggregate call, of which I then _.pluck the _id from both of them.

Array 1 might look like `[ 1 , 57, 58, 100 ]` as an example.
Array 2 might look like `[ 1 , 2, 3, 4, 55, 100 ]` as an example.

I want to find the difference and return and `[ 57, 58 ]`.

To do this I've been using lodash as the library.  And I've tried the following two methods:

```
_.difference(array1, array2)
```

and

```
_.filter(array1, function(obj){ return !_.findWhere(array2, obj); });
```

But both don't seem to work.  I'd love some help if possible.

Comment: If you are aggregating the result, why not use [`$setDifference`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/setDifference/) operator and get it done on the server side rather than doing it on the client side - any specific reasons?

Comment: Also, I believe you're getting back ObjectId objects. If this is the case, then `_.difference` would not work since it's only operating on primitives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ignore.  Turns out the filter code worked.  It was my db with the error.

```
_.filter(array1, function(obj){ return !_.findWhere(array2, obj); });
```